# Django ModelAdmin get_form() doesn't set fields attribute

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I've overriden `get_form()` in my `ModelAdmin` class:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(ModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

Now, if I add this line:

```
print form.fields
```

I get an:

```
AttributeError: type object 'FilerImageForm' has no attribute 'fields'
```

Why is this happening? Should the call to the super `get_form()` set the `fields` attribute on the form? If I am mistaken, how can I access fields on a form in a `ModelAdmin` class?

Comment: Then what's the main thing that `get_form()` should do? Also, if that's the case, how can I access fields on a form in a `ModelAdmin` class?

Answer (score 3):

`get_form` returns class not instance and `fields` attribute is instance attribute. So, you have to instantiate form before accessing fields.

Definition from django/contrib/admin/options.py:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Returns a Form class for use in the admin add view. This is used by
    add_view and change_view.
    """
```

update:

> I need to intercept form field creation, not the view. I need to
>   change a field's value, not mess with a template's context. I don't
>   think add_view() is the appropriate place for this.

I think you can do it by overriding `formfield_for_dbfield` method:

```
def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
    """
    Hook for specifying the form Field instance for a given database Field
    instance.

    If kwargs are given, they're passed to the form Field's constructor.
    """

    formfield = super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)

    if db_field.name == "field_you_are_looking_for":
        # change formfield somehow here
        # (or above, by passing modified kwargs in 'super' call)

    return formfield
```

Comment: Then how do I intercept form creation in a `ModelAdmin` so that I can alter its fields afterwards?

Comment: @AndreiHorak form instantiates in `add_view` and `change_view` `ModelAdmin` methods, check them

Comment: I need to intercept form field creation, not the view. I need to change a field's value, not mess with a template's context. I don't think `add_view()` is the appropriate place for this.